# Making a ListPicker of .png files in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a kind of dropdown list of little .png images in Windows Phone 8.0 c# and it doesn't work! Please Help!

I choosed an ListPicker from the toolkit refrence for Win Phone!

Here is the XAML code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="ListPicker_AdaugarePDI_Image" Grid.Row="0" Width="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="blue">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding imageList}" Height="30">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Then, in the inialization code i wrote :

```
string directory = @".\Resources\imagini1";
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
foreach (string fileImage in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.png"))
{
   Image img = new Image();
   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

   source.UriSource = new Uri(fileImage, UriKind.Relative);
   img.Source = source;
   img.Height = 20;
   img.Width  = 20;
   imageList.Add(img);
}
ListPicker_AdaugarePDI_Image.ItemsSource = imageList;
```

I got no compile error! The pictures are loaded in the code, I checked with breakpoints, but there is no visual representation in the ListPicker!

Should I try with another control other than ListPicker?

Thank you in advanced!

Bogdy19ro

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix to your code:

Here is the XAML code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="ListPicker_AdaugarePDI_Image" Grid.Row="0" Width="70" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="blue">
    <ItemsControl" Height="30">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Here is c# code

```
string directory = @".\Resources\imagini1";
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
foreach (string fileImage in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.png"))
{
   Image img = new Image();
   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

   source.UriSource = new Uri(fileImage, UriKind.Relative);
   img.Source = source;
   img.Height = 20;
   img.Width  = 20;
   imageList.Add(img);
}
ListPicker_AdaugarePDI_Image.ItemsSource = imageList;
```